# Highlight gnuplot pm3d surfaces

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, surface

I got some surfaces using gnuplot/pm3d

[Surfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhzxs.png)

But as you can see there is some recognition problem. How can I hightlight some surface?

- How to add the grid for one surface only?
- How to change the palette for one surface only?
- How to highlight the border of surfaces?

Executive file:

```
 #!/usr/bin/gnuplot

 unset label;                         
 unset tics;                                   
 unset key; unset border; unset colorbox;
 set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10;
 set pm3d interpolate 0,0;         
 splot "1" w pm3d,\
 "2" w pm3d;
```

P.S. The borders of surfaces are pixelated. Is there some method how to make it smooth?